# How to give our style to data pagination in list view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I am faizel and i am a beginner asp.net c#.I am using listview to display contents in my website.but default pagination style in list view doest look good in my website.Can any one tell me how to create page buttons of our own style just like page buttons in youtube.

thank you in advance.god bless you

Answer (score 0):

Just override previous style of pagination with your own css.